# is there any session server for classic asp? or can we manage multiple sessions between different machines and classic asp application?

Tags: session, iis, asp-classic

we have a classic asp web application which has divided into three parts and spread into three different web servers but we want to manage our sessions at the very first place of entering users into the site.

as much as I know there is no official program or method for doing so in classic asp so I was wondering if somebody could help me out with this issue.
-how can we manage sessions between different web servers and classic asp ?
-or is there any session server that gonna be integrated with classic asp?
-or can we cluster our IISes into one and take advantage of doing that according to manage inter-sessions?

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i know you probably dont have this problem anymore but i will still tell you the way i handle that kind of problem.

personally i use a token system

each token is a key in the database and in a second field i drop my session content. everytime i switch webserver i pass the token , once on the other webserver i read it, go to the database and feed my sessions back.

it will ask you some calls to the database everytime you switch webserver to feed the value field in the database and read it back on the other side but once you have the subs all setup it can be really easy to implement good luck :)

Comment: So on each page there is a call to the DB to check/retrieve information? What if it's a web farm and you don't know when there is a webserver switch?

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge, there's no way to share session variables across separate websites. I think your best bet would be to use a combination of session vars and cookies, similar to Microsoft's suggestion for sharing session states between Classic ASP and ASP.NET sites: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx.

Comment: what is your answer about google inter-sessions websites?
and for your information there are solution for creating inte-session mechanism in website either in asp.net and php but I don't have any idea for asp classic